# Unable to request ads in test mode

Tags: ios, testing, ads, mopub

The documentation inside `MPAdView.h` says:

```
/** @name Enabling Test Mode */

/**
 * A Boolean value that determines whether the ad view should request ads in test mode.
 *
 * The default value is NO.
 * @warning **Important**: If you set this value to YES, make sure to reset it to NO before
 * submitting your application to the App Store.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isTesting) BOOL testing;
```

But when requesting a banner using the described test mode:

```
self.adView = [[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:self.adUnitID size:self.size];
self.adView.delegate = self;
self.adView.testing = YES;
[self.adView loadAd];
```

No ad is returned:

```
MOPUB: Banner view (7e99efe0cd814f9d8c946ff530aa9900) failed. Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x167eeef0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://testing.ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=8&udid=ifa:XXXX&id=7e99efe0cd814f9d8c946ff530aa9900&nv=2.4.0&o=l&sc=2.0&z=-0200&mr=1&ct=2&av=1.5&cn=TIM&iso=&mnc=&mcc=&dn=iPhone3%2C1&ts=1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://testing.ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=8&udid=ifa:XXXX&id=7e99efe0cd814f9d8c946ff530aa9900&nv=2.4.0&o=l&sc=2.0&z=-0200&mr=1&ct=2&av=1.5&cn=TIM&iso=&mnc=&mcc=&dn=iPhone3%2C1&ts=1, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x167db490 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}
```

I am using the `MoPub SDK 3.0.0` for iOS.

Is that documentation obsolete? How can I enable test ads?

NOTES:

- My internet connection is Ok;
- I am able to display ads when test mode is equal to `NO`;

Comment: Hello,
Adds are depended on country region. please try to contact  support of MoPub about your country region fill up ratio for adds..

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, what you are doing seems ok.
I would recommend downloading the last version of the MoPub SDK : (3.5.0 at this moment)

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/